# Python Scrapy under MacOSX: no module named twisted.internet and gcc 4.0

Tags: python, gcc, twisted, scrapy

I am a python newbie, trying to learn how to use Scrapy by myself, but I failed at the first step...
I installed Scrapy all right, and followed the instruction on http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html.

After I keyed in "scrapy startproject tutorial" in terminal, it returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/scrapy", line 3, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-        packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 7, in <module>
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-    packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 3, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
ImportError: No module named twisted.internet
```

Then I went to download twisted, and it requires gcc-4.0, which i failed to find its download. My python2.7.3 seems to run on gcc4.0.1, but i don't where it went wrong... here is the last few lines after i keyed in 'pip install twisted' in the terminal (i got my pip running though):

```
gcc-4.0 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -O3 -arch i386 -arch x86_64 -I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c twisted/test/raiser.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.3-intel-2.7/twisted/test/raiser.o

unable to execute gcc-4.0: No such file or directory

error: command 'gcc-4.0' failed with exit status 1
```

---

```
Command     /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/var/folders/ww/7vcs04j95jg4dgcb94t7s5p00000gn/T/pip-build/twisted/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/ww/7vcs04j95jg4dgcb94t7s5p00000gn/T/pip-lfT0hS-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /var/folders/ww/7vcs04j95jg4dgcb94t7s5p00000gn/T/pip-build/twisted
```

My Mac runs on MAcOSX 10.7.5, and I never installed Xcode.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: install xcode, it comes with command line tools which should have the latest version of gcc.

Comment: Thx! but nothing changes after i installed Xcode. i thought i need an earlier version of gcc, gcc4.0, to run twisted, and i don't know how to get gcc4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this exact issue with Scrapy on OSX.  I fixed it by:

- Install Xcode from App Store
- Open Xcode
- Go to "Preferences"
- Select "Download" tab
- Install Command Line Tools

Answer (score 0):

This question is solved! Here is the solution for those who find themselves in the situation:

IF you are using a MacOSX 10.6 and higher, (Mine is MacOSX 10.7.5) and if you wanna use Scrapy, check the version of the Python: download the "Python 2.7.3 Mac OS X 64-bit/32-bit x86-64/i386 Installer" from the official page, download the right version of ActiveTcl, and test Python: it should use a gcc 4.2.1.

Then, install pip, and then Scrapy, twisted, zope, and any other module Scrapy wants.

(I actually installed gcc4.2.1 before I installed the right version of Python. So if the solution above is not sufficient, try installing gcc4.2.1)

Credits to Computer Pros @ Kalamazoo College!